# Why I can not do “or” in my JavaScript if condition?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have following function which behaves differently when I add an OR condition in it.

```
<script>
function checkfield(obj)
{
    var full_name = obj.upload_image.value.toLowerCase();
    var full_length = parseInt(full_name.length);
    var dotAt = parseInt(full_name.lastIndexOf("."));

    var ext = full_name.substring((dotAt+1), full_length);
    if(ext == "jpg" || ext == "png")
        {
            //alert("Sorry! allowed file types are .png, .gif, .jpg");
            //return false;
            console.log("Correct Extention");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Wrong extention");
        }


    return false;
}
</script>
```

What ever I give before the `||` operator it works fine and the second one fails. please can some one pick out what i am doing wrong or how this should be done.

Comment: @molvi You don't have to parseInt the value of the length property of a string...

Comment: This should work. Can you give examples of the filenames you are trying to input?

Comment: @molvi You can do this check with regexp in one line (without all those variables). `if ( full_name.search(/(\.jpg|\.png)$/i) !== -1 ) { ...`

Comment: file names are simply test.PNG , jpg.jpg

Comment: don't forget .jpeg is also a valid extension so you better use regex (as Šime Vidas proposed) `full_name.search(/(\.jpe?g|\.png|\.gif)$/i) !== -1`

Comment: Is the extension in UPPERCASE ? The above regex handles it. I prefer to use `.test` instead though: `/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(full_name)`

Comment: i have already made the whole file name in lower case and tested it i dont know what is going wrong

Comment: I was wondering if this was going to turn into a (who can optimize their regex the most) war. :P I do agree that a regex would probably be better than what he's doing, though. But uppercase isn't the issue as he's converting the whole file name to lowercase before extracting the extension. I'd have to wage it's a trimming issue.

Comment: Zooming out a little, I hope that the OP knows that a file can be a perfectly good jpeg or PNG image without having one of those extensions on the file name.  Similarly, a file can be something wildly different from a jpeg or PNG image and *have* such a file name. It's pointless to filter input this way.

Comment: @Pointy: can you please suggest how it should be done then ? thanks

Comment: @Gmolvi - Can you give us an example of how you're CALLING this function?

Comment: I have tested this function and it works OK for me :)

Comment: If it's important that the file be a particular type, you **must** inspect the actual file contents, and you must do it on your server. You can *also* do it on the client, but you'll have to use the new HTML5 file access APIs in order to "sniff" the contents. Personally I use the ImageMagick tools on my site to perform exactly this work, because checking for image file types is non-trivial.  (Well, it's not that hard, but somebody else has already done it for me.)

Comment: @Pointy - While I don't disagree with you, it's not always necessary to do more robust detection from the start. If the OP can give immediate feedback to the user that they're attempting to upload an incorrect file without performing a round-trip to the server it would aid in usability of the site/app/etc. ----- I would also argue it's important he find out the issue with the offending code as well rather than move onto a different solution all-together.

Comment: @Karolis:  how is it working on your browser? what browser did you tested it on.

Comment: @G molvi, I tested it on Firefox.

Comment: @G molvi, here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/tJ4ck/2/ and it works! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a regex you can validate multiple extensions in one line.

```
// allows: jpeg, jpg, png, gif
if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(full_name))
{
}
```

Comment: This is awesome regex. works perfect but i still dont get the logic why the above was failing even after applying trim and confirming the values as soon i put OR Operator it fails ...

Answer (score 5):

your conditional is fine, the problem is probably with the value in `ext`.  I would `console.log` it or look at the value in the debugger, its probably not what you think it is.

[image]

EDIT, from the comments, you said the file name was text.PNG.  "PNG" is not the same as "png"

Comment: in the debugger i have correct exttion comming up as png , jpg, do i have to trim it ? or any thing else on it

Comment: @G yes try trimming it, just incase the value is something like 'png ' and not 'png'

Comment: if you ask whether f.ex. "png " == "png" then NO. So you'd have to trim it obviously to make it equal

Comment: @Gmolvi - Here are some trim functions in JavaScript using either regex's or loops: http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

Comment: i tried trim from phpjs but still no use. and i believe the value doesn't need trimming as i have confimed it in console.log and debugger .

Comment: @G, look at my screenshot.  Something else is wrong.  How about you very clearly describe what you expect and what is happening

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
<script>
function checkfield(obj)
{
    var full_name = obj.upload_image.value.toLowerCase();
    var full_length = parseInt(full_name.length);
    var dotAt = parseInt(full_name.lastIndexOf("."));

    var ext = full_name.substring((dotAt+1), full_length);
    if(trim(ext) == "jpg" || trim(ext) == "png")
        {
            //alert("Sorry! allowed file types are .png, .gif, .jpg");
            //return false;
            console.log("Correct Extention");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Wrong extention");
        }


    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `OR` operator (just `||`)

Comment: And even if it did, it would be lowercase =)

Comment: according to my knowledge JavaScript does not have `trim()`